# mediadisplay complete

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am use Mediadisplay in stage. I want to make show button When video is complete.
But not show play button after video completed. How can I do this. Thanks for answers.

```
general.video_button.onRelease = function(){
    general.video.play(0);
    general.video_button._visible = false;
}

general.video.complete = function (){
    general.video_button._visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am make.

```
general.video.addEventListener("complete",example); 

function example(){
    general.video_button._visible = true;
}
```